# Google Spreadsheet to Google form - Create Answers key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

```
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('test1');
  const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const choices = {};
 
  header.forEach(function(title, index) {
    choices[title] = data.map(row => row[index]).filter(e => e !== '');
  });

  //Logger.log(choices);
  //Logger.log(TitleA);

  return choices;
}

function myFunction1() {
  const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  
  var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

  for (var i in choices) {
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      // I was going to write the if function with "i = i +1" here.
      .setTitle(i) 
      .setChoiceValues(choices[i]) // .setChoiceValues(choices[i], true) --- All answer Check;;;
      .showOtherOption(true);
  }
}
```

With all the materials produced in VBA, I am thinking of aligning the answer to A in column 1 and randomly turning it into a form in Google Script.

---

[Add - 230710]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU7cP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tamr8.png)

1. Title : 1. Find food?
2. Question : a. cat, b. dog, c. pizza(red, Answer) d. clothes, e. tire

Google Spread Sheet to Google Form

1. Title and Question = Okay
2. I want to put in the answer key, but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result from `1. I'm trying to check the answer with number 1 fixed in the code below (I'm thinking of turning the random code when I open it while it's made) 2. The arrangement goes in at once 3. I can't hold it as an "if function" in the same way as "i = i + 1".`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hello.
Thank you for your reply every time. Tanaike,

I answer VBA every time, too,
It is often difficult to answer if you don't talk about the original.
So I added the intention that I was going to produce.
I was very surprised by your reply last time. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. From your updated question, do you want to convert XLSX to Google Spreadsheet? And, I cannot understand `1.1 - Title/2 - 5 - Data, 2. I still have the issue of turning the red answer check on the spreadsheet into a form.`. Is your added image a sample input situation of XLSX data? If my understanding is correct, can I see your expected situation?

Comment: I wrote too complicatedly, so I modified the content.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I can make myselft, but my code worse than what you made.

  for (var i in choices) {
    var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      item.setRequired(true)
      item.setTitle(i) 
      .setChoices([
        item.createChoice(choices[i][0], true),
        item.createChoice(choices[i][1]),
        item.createChoice(choices[i][2]),
        item.createChoice(choices[i][3]),
        item.createChoice(choices[i][4])
      ])

Comment: I have to make more than 200 like that in the future, and I was very confused because it was expected to take about 10 hours or more.
The code below has worked now, and thank you for doing so well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set `correctColor`. From your showing Spreadsheet image, I guessed it might be `#ff0000`. So, please confirm it and modify it.

```js
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
  const correctColor = "#ff0000"; // Please set this for your actual situation.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('test1');
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const ar = range.getDisplayValues();
  const choices = ar[0].map((_, col) => ar.map((row) => row[col])).map(([h, ...v]) => [h, v]);
  const correct = range.getTextStyles().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c.getForegroundColorObject().asRgbColor().asHexString() == correctColor) {
        ar.push([i - 1, j]);
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return { choices, correct };
}

function myFunction1() {
  const { choices, correct } = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  const form = FormApp.create('New Form');
  form.setIsQuiz(true);
  choices.forEach(([h, v], j) => {
    const q = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(h).showOtherOption(true);
    const cv = v.map((e, i) => q.createChoice(e, correct[j][0] == i ? true : false));
    q.setChoices(cv);
  });
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run using your showing Spreadsheet, a new Google Form is created as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for being so nice from yesterday to today. / Super Good! / have nice day!

Comment: Hello, Tanaike,
Last time I increased the above question to 20~30, the red has an error in the [correct answer] position, can you check it?

Comment: @seed13 About your new question of `I increased the above question to 20~30, the red has an error in the [correct answer] position, can you check it?`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @seed13 By the way, unfortunately, from `I increased the above question to 20~30, the red has an error in the [correct answer] position, can you check it?`, I cannot understand your situation. So, when you post it as a new question, please include more information.